# Play all songs by the same artist on iOS

Tags: ios, music.app, album

How can one play all the songs from a particular artist or group sequentially from different albums? Currently I have to open up the next album of the same artist or even the same album if songs from it were purchased at different times.

Comment: May I suggest you to give Cesium a try?

Answer (score 2):

- Open Music app
- Tap (repeatly) on the Library button at bottom left until you get to the top level
- Tap on Artists
- Select the artist you want
- Top row allows to play all titles across all albums at random, tap that
- Open the currently playing view
- Scroll down a bit and disable shuffle mode

PS: I didn't say it's easy that way but it works well for those artists you haven't defined a Smart Playlist for.

Comment: I believe this functionality doesn't exist on iPad. Which is a weird discontinuity. For some reason even Siri plays only Apple Music songs (even if you hide Apple Music in the settings).
Perhaps the easiest workaround is to search the name of the artist in the Search tab, scroll down to the list of songs, press "See All" and then the Shuffle button on top.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to [create a Smart Playlist in iTunes](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19487?locale=en_US) that looks for all the music by that artist, then sync it with your iOS device. The playlist on your iOS device will automatically update whenever you add new music to your library by that artist and re-sync.